# How to remove previous style during javaFX animation

Tags: java, animation, javafx, conways-game-of-life

I am making a version of Game of Life but am having trouble removing the background color of cells that should be dying.

---

Code (extract):

```
public class Life extends Application {
private static int DIM = 32;
private Cell[][] cell = new Cell[DIM][DIM];
private boolean[][] nextState = new boolean[DIM][DIM];
private Timeline animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), e -> step()));
private RadioButton rbLife = new RadioButton("Life");
private RadioButton rbHLife = new RadioButton("HighLife");
private Button step = new Button("Step");
private Button playStop = new Button("Play");
private Button clear = new Button("Clear");
private Slider slRate = new Slider();
private Label rate = new Label("Rate: ");


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
            pane.add(cell[i][j] = new Cell(), j, i);

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setCenter(pane);
    borderPane.setBottom(getHBox());

public void step() {
    for (int i=0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            computeNextState(i, j);
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            cell[i][j].updateState(nextState[i][j], i, j);

        }
    }
}

public boolean[][] computeNextState(int row, int col) {
    int liveCount = 0;
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
            if (cell[(row + i + DIM) % DIM][(col + j + DIM) % DIM].isAlive())
                liveCount++;
            if (cell[row][col].isAlive())
                liveCount--;
            if (rbLife.isSelected()) {
                if (liveCount == 3 || cell[row][col].isAlive() && liveCount == 2) {
                    nextState[row][col] = true;
                }
                else
                    nextState[row][col] = false;
            }
    return nextState;
}

public class Cell extends Pane {
    private char token = ' ';

    public Cell() {
        setStyle("-fx-border-color: white; -fx-border-width: .17;");
        this.setPrefSize(100, 100);
        this.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleMouseClick());
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        if (token == 'a') {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public char getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(char c) {
        token = c;
    }

    private void handleMouseClick() {
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        setToken('a');
    }

    public void updateState(boolean state, int row, int col) {
        if (state == true) {
            setToken('a');
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        }
        else
            setToken(' ');
            //cell[row][col].setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
    }
}
```

---

In updateState() I have tried setting the background to black, null, clearing the style with getStyleClass().clear().

Setting the background to empty with setBackground() will repaint them black, but then the cells cannot be repainted green on the following generation. What am i missing here?

I have omitted parts that I think are irrelevant fyi. Thank you for any TIPS!

Answer (score 0):

> In `updateState()` I have tried setting the background to black, null,

This does not work since CSS styles have higher priority than the `background` property.

> clearing the style with `getStyleClass().clear()`.

This does not work since it simply clears the style classes of the node. You're using a inline style though.

---

You should set the background the same way in both cases:

```
if (state) {
    setToken('a');
    setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
} else {
    setToken(' ');
    setStyle("-fx-border-color: white; -fx-border-width: .17;"); // or null if you don't want to revert to the original style
}
```

or assuming you remove the background properties from all parameters passed to `setStyle`:

```
private static final FALSE_BACKGROUND = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));
private static final TRUE_BACKGROUND = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREEN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));

...

if (state) {
    setToken('a');
    setBackground(TRUE_BACKGROUND);
} else {
    setToken(' ');
    setBackground(FALSE_BACKGROUND);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! There was a major/fundamental syntax error too that caused most of my problems...thanks for subtly pointing out. Never seeking others to do my work that's exactly what I was looking for!